# Guava cache: how to set expiration on 'CacheLoader.load()' instead of during CacheBuilder.newBuilder()?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I am trying to create a cache using guava cache library. One my main requirement is that I want to set the cache expiry after the CacheLoader.load(..) function instead of something most of the examples I encountered on the web, like the one below.

```
LoadingCache<String, MyClass> myCache = 
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(MAX_SIZE).expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.Minutes).build(cacheLoader);
```

The reason for this is that the object retrieved from the database by the CacheLoader.load(...) function contains the expiration data. So I want to use this information instead of some "random" static value.

I want something like this.

```
LoadingCache<String, MyClass> myCache = 
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(MAX_SIZE).build(cacheLoader);
```

...

```
CacheLoader meCacheLoder = new CacheLoader<String MyClass>(){
   @Override
   public MyClass load(String key) throws Exception {
      // Retrieve the MyClass object from database using 'key'
      MyClass myObj = getMyObjectFromDb(key);  
      int expiry = myObj.getExpiry();

         // Now somehow set this 'expiry' value with the cache
         ????

      return myObj;
   }
 };
```

OR
Is there any better option available than Guava cache for this purpose?

Comment: No, there is no way to set per-entry expiration times with Guava's cache.  See https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1203 for some discussion.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Guava Cache - Change the eviction timeout values during run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843814/google-guava-cache-change-the-eviction-timeout-values-during-run-time)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in Guava, as Louis already pointed out.

For example you can use EHCache or [cache2k](http://cache2k.org). For cache2k I can give you quick directions since this is a core feature we use regularly:

You can either implement the interface `ValueWithExpiryTime` on your value object, which is:

```
interface ValueWithExpiryTime {

  long getCacheExpiryTime();

}
```

Or, you can register a `EntryExpiryCalculator` to extract the time value. The cache is build as follows:

```
Cache<Key, Value> cache = 
  CacheBuilder.newCache(Key.class, Value.class)
    .expiryCalculator(new EntryExpiryCalculator<Key, Value>() {
        @Override
        public long calculateExpiryTime(
            final Key key, final Value value, 
            final long loadTime, final CacheEntry<Key, Value> oldEntry) {
          return value.getExpiry();
        }
      }
    )
    .build();
```

The time is the standard long type represented in milliseconds since the epoch. By default the expiry will happen not exactly at the specified time, but zero or a few milliseconds later, depending on your machine load. This is the most effective mode. If this is a problem, add `sharpExpiry(true)`.

Disclaimer: I am the author of cache2k....